# In Chrome extension Manifest v3, how do i instruct manifest.json to run my extension only on certain webpages without using activeTab permission?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Whenever i hover over my ext icon, i get the tooltip "Wants access to this site" which is wrong because it should want access only on youtube.com/watch?v=* (and it's another story that Manifest 'match' refuses to accept `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*` as a valid URL)

This is what i'm currently doing:

```
// manifest.json

{
    "name": "YouTube Overlay",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version" : 3,
    "description": "Lays overlay on YouTube, can be used for guitar chords/lyrics.",
    "background" : {
        "service_worker" : "bg.js"
    },
    "action": {},
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["funcsTBInsertedIntoDOM.js"],
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"]
    }]
}

// bg.js

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {  
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tab.id},
            files: ['yt.js'],
    });
});
```

`yt.js` when executed above, injects a bunch of HTML elems & CSS rules into DOM. It also injects `funcsTBInsertedIntoDOM.js` (specified in `web_accessible_resources` in the manifest.json above) into DOM, which contains function definitions for the injected HTML buttons.

So basically whenever the user clicks on my ext icon, bg.js executes, which in turn executes yt.js. When the user clicks while on a YouTube video, it works fine. But otherwise it throws errors in the console naturally. So how do i instruct the manifest to execute bg.js ONLY on YouTube videos? (it shouldn't even run on other YouTube pages, just only when user is on a video page).

Also, i got a rejection notice from Google Web Store for my extension:

```
Violation(s):

    Use of Permissions:

        Violation reference ID: Purple Potassium
        Violation: Requesting but not using the following permission(s):
            activeTab
        How to rectify: Remove the above permission(s)
```

But if i remove `activeTab` permission, my extension doesn't work at all.

If someone could propose a solution with both of these problems in mind, i'd be very grateful. Thank you for reading.

Adding additional code to help make it easier:

This is yt.ts:

```
// all global variables are 'var' instead of let or const because the delete command works only on var
var isFullScreen = false;
var extensionActivated = false;
var resCheckerID:number;
var chordsTALeftPaddingNonFS = chordsTALeftPaddingNonFSOnExit;
var chordsTALeftPaddingFS = "0px";
var thisIsThe1stExitAfterFS = true;

var activateExtension = () => { 
  console.log("YouTube Overlay activated.");
  let scriptElemForASBtn = document.createElement("style");
  let innardsForASBtn = styleForAsBtn;
  scriptElemForASBtn.innerHTML = innardsForASBtn;
  document.head.appendChild(scriptElemForASBtn);
  
  const videoElem = document.querySelector("video");
  const vidBottomPanel = document.querySelector(".ytp-chrome-bottom");
  const progBarPadding = document.querySelector(".ytp-progress-bar-padding");
  
  const getIdealChordsDivStyles = (isFullScreen:boolean) => {
    let vidDims = videoElem.getBoundingClientRect();
    let progBarPaddingDims = progBarPadding.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (isFullScreen){
      console.log("fullscreen detected")
      thisIsThe1stExitAfterFS = true;
      chordsTALeftPaddingNonFS = chordsTA.style.paddingLeft; // saving this for next nonFS
      chordsTA.style.paddingLeft = chordsTALeftPaddingFS; // assigning this from prev FS
      return `overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1111; width: 100vw; height: ${progBarPaddingDims.y - vidDims.y + (progBarPaddingDims.height/2)}px`;
    } else {
      try {
        if(thisIsThe1stExitAfterFS) 
          chordsTALeftPaddingFS = chordsTA.style.paddingLeft;
          chordsTA.style.paddingLeft = chordsTALeftPaddingNonFS;
          thisIsThe1stExitAfterFS = false;
      } catch {} // saving this for next FS. on first run it obsly won't be able to find chordsTA.
      return `overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1111; left: ${vidDims.x}px; top: ${vidDims.y}px; width: ${vidDims.width}px; height: ${progBarPaddingDims.y - vidDims.y + (progBarPaddingDims.height/2)}px`;
    }
  }
    
  
  // creating the chords div 
  let chordsDiv = document.createElement('div');
  chordsDiv.style.cssText = getIdealChordsDivStyles(isFullScreen);
  chordsDiv.setAttribute("id", "chordsDiv");

  let htmlInnards = `
  <div id="chordsCtrls" onmouseover="unhideChordsCtrls();" onmouseout="hideChordsCtrls();" style="z-index: 1112; height: ${vidBottomPanel.getBoundingClientRect().height}px; position: absolute; display: inline-block;">
      <a id="asBtn" onclick="toggleAutoScroll()" class="btn-flip" data-back="Turn on" data-front="Auto-Scroll Off"></a>
      <a id="decTxtSize" class="btn noselect" onclick="decTxtSize();">Tᵀ</a>
      <a id="incTxtSize" class="btn noselect" onclick="incTxtSize();">ᵀT</a>
      <a id="decIndent" class="btn noselect" onclick="decIndent();">¶-</a>
      <a id="incIndent" class="btn noselect" onclick="incIndent();">¶+</a>

  </div>
  <textarea onkeyup="checkTAWidth();" onclick="checkTAWidth();" id="chordsTA" spellcheck="false" style="position:absolute; left:50%; transform: translate(-50%,0); white-space: pre; overflow-wrap: normal; overflow-x: scroll; font-family: Roboto Mono,monospace; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35); color: white; height: 100%; min-width:10vw; font-size: ${window.screen.height*0.026}px;" placeholder="\n\nPaste\nyour\nchords/lyrics\nin\nhere!">
  `
  
  chordsDiv.innerHTML = htmlInnards;

  document.body.appendChild(chordsDiv);

  chordsTA.value = lyricsOnExit; // doing in convoluted way because i cant fig it out :S
  if (chordsTA.value === "undefined") chordsTA.value = "";
  chordsTA.scrollTop = lyricsLocOnExit;
  chordsTA.style.fontSize = lyricsSizeOnExit;
  chordsTA.style.paddingLeft = chordsTALeftPaddingNonFS;
  console.log("Lyrics reinstated, if any.");

  
  // hiding the scrollbar of chords div & textarea
  let styleForScrollbarHiding = `#chordsDiv::-webkit-scrollbar, #chordsTA::-webkit-scrollbar {height: 0; width: 0;}`;
  let styleSheet = document.createElement("style");
  styleSheet.type = "text/css";
  styleSheet.innerText = styleForScrollbarHiding;
  document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);

  // auto sizing of chords div
function resCheck() {
    let vidDims = videoElem.getBoundingClientRect();
    let chordsDims = chordsDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    let requisiteHtForChordsDiv =  vidDims.height - vidBottomPanel.getBoundingClientRect().height- (progBarPadding.getBoundingClientRect().height/2);
    if (((chordsDims.x !== vidDims.x || chordsDims.width !== vidDims.width) && chordsDims.x !== 0) || (chordsDims.x === 0 && chordsDims.x !== vidDims.x)) { // base cond's latter gets True when exiting from FS. Base's former's former checks in non fullScn mode if x or width is wrong.
      if (isFullScreen && vidDims.y === 0) return;
      console.log("Video dimensions changed detected, redrawing overlay.");
      isFullScreen = vidDims.y === 0 ? true : false;
      chordsDiv.style.cssText = getIdealChordsDivStyles(isFullScreen);
    }
  }
  resCheckerID = setInterval(resCheck, 2000);

  // addding my JS functions to the youtube HTML webpage/DOM
  let s = document.createElement('script');
  // TODO: add "scriptName.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
  s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('funcsTBInsertedIntoDOM.js');
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
}


var styleForAsBtn = `
#asBtn {
    opacity: 1;
    outline: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #asBtn:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0);
  }
  #asBtn:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  #asBtn:after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    background: #BCBCBC;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.25s;
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-back);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  #asBtn:before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #323237;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 40px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    position: relative;
    content: attr(data-front);
    transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0);
  }

  /* CSS for other buttons */
  .btn{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#666666 0%, #323237  100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#666666 0%, #323237 100%);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    font-size: x-large;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .btn:active{
    color: #000000;
  } 
  .btn:hover {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#999999 0%, #323237 100%);    
    background-image: linear-gradient(#999999 0%, #323237 100%);
  }
  .noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
      -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                    supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
  }

  #incTxtSize, #decTxtSize{
    font-size: large;
  }

  #chordsCtrls>*{
    transition: transform 0.1s linear;
  }

  textarea::placeholder {
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 4vh;
  }

  #contentContainer.tp-yt-app-drawer[swipe-open].tp-yt-app-drawer::after{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
`
// the last css property above is hiding a thin left side vertical area which otherwise causes chordsCtrls not to show up if mouse is on extreme left. Also causes difficulty clicking SpeedDn button.

if (!document.querySelector("#chordsDiv")){
  activateExtension();
} else {
  console.log("YouTube Overlay deactivated");
  var lyricsOnExit = chordsTA.value;
  var lyricsLocOnExit = chordsTA.scrollTop;
  var lyricsSizeOnExit = chordsTA.style.fontSize;
  var chordsTALeftPaddingNonFSOnExit = chordsTA.style.paddingLeft; // won't be possible to save FS padding unless i deactivate extension with an X btn. Due to scope prob.
  document.querySelector("#chordsDiv").remove();
  clearInterval(resCheckerID);
  delete window.resCheckerID;
}
```

This is funcsTBInsertedIntoDOM.ts:

```
console.log("Loading essential funcs needed for YouTube Overlay extension.")

clearInterval(asIntervalID); // cannot clear this from yt.ts because yt.ts runs in a sandbox. So need to clear it here, if it exists, on startup. Thankfully doesn't throw error even if doesn't exist.
clearTimeout(hideChordsCtrlsTimeoutID);

var asSpeeds = {1: 250, 2: 150, 3: 100, 4: 90, 5: 75, 6: 60, 7: 50, 8: 40, 9: 30};

var chordsCtrls:HTMLDivElement = document.querySelector("#chordsCtrls");
var chordsTA:HTMLTextAreaElement = document.querySelector("#chordsTA");
var asBtn:HTMLButtonElement = document.querySelector("#asBtn");
var autoScrollSpeed = 250;
var asIntervalID = 0;

function toggleAutoScroll() {
    if(asIntervalID){
        clearInterval(asIntervalID);
        asIntervalID = 0;
        console.log("Stopped autoscroll.");
        document.querySelector("#speedUp").remove(); document.querySelector("#speedDn").remove();
        setAttributes(asBtn, {"data-front": `Auto-Scroll Off`, 'data-back': 'Turn On'});
        return;
    }
    
    // create speed + - buttons
    let speedUp = document.createElement("a");
    speedUp.textContent = "+";
    setAttributes(speedUp, {'id': 'speedUp', 'class': 'btn noselect', 'onclick': 'speedUpAS();'});
    document.querySelector("#chordsCtrls").insertBefore(speedUp,document.querySelector("#decTxtSize"));
    let speedDn = document.createElement("a");
    speedDn.textContent = "-";
    setAttributes(speedDn, {'id': 'speedDn', 'class': 'btn noselect', 'onclick': 'speedDnAS();'});
    document.querySelector("#chordsCtrls").insertBefore(speedDn,asBtn);;

    setAttributes(asBtn, {"data-front": `Speed: ${getKeyByValue(asSpeeds,autoScrollSpeed)}`, 'data-back': 'Turn Off'});

    asIntervalID = setInterval(_=>{chordsTA.scrollBy(0, 1)}, autoScrollSpeed);
    console.log("Started autoscroll.")
}

var speedUpAS = () => {
    console.log("Speeding up autoscroll")
    let asBtnText = asBtn.getAttribute('data-front');
    let newSpeed:number = parseInt(asBtnText.charAt(asBtnText.length - 1))+1;
    if (newSpeed in asSpeeds){
        clearInterval(asIntervalID);
        autoScrollSpeed = asSpeeds[newSpeed];
        asIntervalID = 0;
        asBtn.setAttribute('data-front', `Speed: ${getKeyByValue(asSpeeds, autoScrollSpeed)}`);
        asIntervalID = setInterval(_=>{chordsTA.scrollBy(0, 1)}, autoScrollSpeed);
    }
}

var speedDnAS = () => {
    console.log("Speeding down autoscroll")
    let asBtnText = asBtn.getAttribute('data-front');
    let newSpeed:number = parseInt(asBtnText.charAt(asBtnText.length - 1))-1;
    if (newSpeed in asSpeeds){
        clearInterval(asIntervalID);
        autoScrollSpeed = asSpeeds[newSpeed];
        asIntervalID = 0;
        asBtn.setAttribute('data-front', `Speed: ${getKeyByValue(asSpeeds, autoScrollSpeed)}`);
        asIntervalID = setInterval(_=>{chordsTA.scrollBy(0, 1)}, autoScrollSpeed);
    }
}  

var incTxtSize = () => {
    let currFontSize = parseFloat(chordsTA.style.fontSize);
    let newFontSize = currFontSize += 1;
    chordsTA.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
    qickSizeUp();
}

var decTxtSize = () => {
    let currFontSize = parseFloat(chordsTA.style.fontSize);
    let newFontSize = currFontSize -= 1;
    chordsTA.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
    qickSizeDn();
}

var unhideChordsCtrls = () => {
    clearTimeout(hideChordsCtrlsTimeoutID);
    let childrenOfchordsCtrlsDiv:any = chordsCtrls.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (let index = 0; index < childrenOfchordsCtrlsDiv.length; index++) {
        childrenOfchordsCtrlsDiv[index].style.transform = "translate(0,0)";
    }
}

var hideChordsCtrlsTimeoutID = 0;
var hideChordsCtrls = () => {
    hideChordsCtrlsTimeoutID = setTimeout(() => {        
        let childrenOfchordsCtrlsDiv:any = chordsCtrls.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (let index = 0; index < childrenOfchordsCtrlsDiv.length; index++) {
            childrenOfchordsCtrlsDiv[index].style.transform = "translate(0,-100%)";
        }
    }, 2000);
}

hideChordsCtrlsTimeoutID = setTimeout(() => { //hide the controls after initially showing them for 4 secs
    hideChordsCtrls();
}, 4000);

var decIndent = () => {
    let newLeftPadding = (parseInt(chordsTA.style.paddingLeft) - 50);
    if (!newLeftPadding) newLeftPadding = 0; // this catches NaN on first run, as it is not set. Also doesn't allow to go less than 0 somehow, luckily.
    chordsTA.style.paddingLeft = `${newLeftPadding}px`;
}

var incIndent = () => {
    let newLeftPadding = (parseInt(chordsTA.style.paddingLeft) + 50);
    if (!newLeftPadding) newLeftPadding = 50; // this catches NaN on first run, as it is not set. 
    if (newLeftPadding > document.querySelector("#chordsDiv").getBoundingClientRect().width) return;
    chordsTA.style.paddingLeft = `${newLeftPadding}px`;
}

// following funcs stolen from SO for finding a key by its value & setting attributes multiple at a time.
function getKeyByValue(object:object, value:Number) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
  }

function setAttributes(el:HTMLElement, attrs:object) {
    for(var key in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
}
}
```

Or you may prefer to read the code over at GitHub: https://github.com/XtremePwnership/YoutubeOverlay

Comment: [The `matches`, `extension_ids`, and `use_dynamic_url` keys are not available yet. Support for these properties will be coming in a future release.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#web-accessible-resources).

Comment: Dang. Any idea why they rejected my extension for "Violation: Requesting but not using the following permission(s): activeTab". I'm clearly using the activeTab, aren't I? They tell me to remove it, but if I remove it the extension doesn't work at all!

Comment: If you are 100% sure you are using it and are mistakenly getting this error message, then just use it for something that does nothing.

Comment: How do i check if i'm ACTUALLY using that permission? The `yt.js` file injects HTML, CSS & JS into the tab which is in the foreground when user clicks on ext icon. Isn't that enough justification that i'm using the activeTab permission? Alternatively can you suggest a way to make it work without the activeTab permission? Thanks.

Comment: There are many reasons this could happen. Perhaps your implementation of that permission is wrong. Perhaps your script is not getting injected. It is impossible to tell using only the info you've given.

Comment: Please let me know what other information should i provide.

Comment: You need to provide the code that is making use of this permission.

Comment: Ok, i have added the code contained inside `yt.ts` & `funcsTBInsertedIntoDOM.ts` to my original question. Would appreciate if you could take a look, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since YouTube video pages are hosted at `youtube.com/watch`, specifying that in your manifest is the way to go:

```
{
    "name": "YouTube Overlay",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version" : 3,
    "description": "Lays overlay on YouTube, can be used for guitar chords/lyrics.",
    "background" : {
        "service_worker" : "bg.js"
    },
    "action": {},
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["funcsTBInsertedIntoDOM.js"],
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to inform, i already tried that pattern but doesn't work. I get this error: `Invalid value for 'web_accessible_resources[0]'. Invalid match pattern. Could not load manifest.`. Also, is there a way to do this without requesting the activeTab permission? I wish to reinstate my extension on Chrome store.